# Java, Spring: Testing DAOs for DataAccessException with Mockito

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, jdbc

I'm trying to increase my test coverage so I'm wondering, how would you go about testing for DataAccessExceptions being thrown in a DAO, for example in a simple findAll method which just returns all the data from your data source? In my case, I'm using Spring JdbcTemplates.

For general testing I have my setUp-method with an @Before annotation, mocking the jdbcTemplate used, setting it up in the DAO and mocking all jdbc calls. Now forcing a DataAccessException for something like a create method is pretty simple, just throw the exception when calling a create statement with the right primary keys.

However, I really have no idea how to handle this for methods like simple findAll methods which don't take any input parameters. Testing the valid implementation is straight forward, but how would you go about mocking having no DB connection without it affecting every other test or method?

This would be a concrete implementation of a method I'd like to test:

```
  public List<SomeObject> findAll() throws PersistenceException {
    final String sql = "SELECT * FROM SomeObject";

    try {
      return jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new JdbcSomeObjectMapper());
    } catch (DataAccessException ex) {
      LOG.error(ex.getMessage());
      throw new PersistenceException(ex.getMessage());
    }
  }
```

Which would just return all objects in the data source. Testing for a valid call is easy since I can just mock the jdbcTemplate.query call, but I'd never enter the catch block unless there's a connection failure while retrieving the data, and that's what I'd like to test.

Comment: What would you test? The DAO shouldn't handle this exception, it should just bubble up the stack until it can be handled, typically by displaying an error message to the end user.

Comment: How would you deal with it, then? It doesn't really handle it, it just logs the exception happening and delegates a new exception to the next layer. And they really should only happen when there's no connection to the database, and that's what I'd like to test, without destroying all other tests.

Comment: Spring already unifies persistence-related exceptions for you. I don't see any point in cluttering every method of every DAO just to translate a technical Spring persistence exception into another custom persistence exception. Anyway, if you want us to show how you could unit-test such a case, you should post the code to test, and what you have tried already to test it.

Comment: You're right, I should have probably done that from the beginning. Updated the original post.

Comment: OK. So what did you try? What's the concrete difficulty? You need to mock the JdbcTemplate, tell it to throw an exception when query is called, then call findAll(), and check it throws a PersistenceException.

Comment: Say I have two tests. The first test tests for the valid implementation of the method, while the second one tests for an error while calling it. If I mock the jdbcTemplate.query call for my findAll method, how would I make sure my tests actually call the right one for each test? I can't really mock the call twice since the call itself does not change, but the outcome should depending on the test.

Comment: Each test should be independant from the others. They should both mock the template as it needs to be mocked for what the test needs to check, then create a DAO instance with that mock, then call the method, the check it does the right thing. Once again, it would be much easier if you posted your code. Note that *unit*-testing the method is pretty useless: you'll check that you're executing the query using the template. What does that test? Not much. You still have no idea if the query is correct, returns the expected data, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Using Mockito you can mock a Class and the method calls of that particular Class. A mocked object can also be asked to throw an exception when particular methods are called on it. First you have to mock your jdbcTemplate, then stub your exception

```
   //mocking JdbcTemplate
JdbcTemplate template = Mockito.mock(JdbcTemplate.class);
Mockito.when(template.query(Mockito.anyString(), (RowMapper<YourClass>)  Mockito.any(RowMapper.class))).thenThrow(EmptyResultDataAccessException.class);

    //or using EasyMock
 EasyMock.expect(template.query(Mockito.anyString(), (RowMapper<YourClass>)  Mockito.any(RowMapper.class))).andThrow(new (typeofExecption));
```