# Testing Spring service for DB errors with Mockito

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, mockito

Following this question- [Java, Spring: Testing DAOs for DataAccessException with Mockito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38040567/java-spring-testing-daos-for-dataaccessexception-with-mockito): 
I'm mocking the JPA repository, and configuring it to throw a DataAccessException on save method. But I'm not sure **how to mock having no DB connection**?
And also- is DataAccessException will be thrown by the JPA repository for every exception?

Thanks!

Comment: If you mock the repository, there is no database associated to the mock so nothing to do

Comment: Ok, so how can I mock DB connection errors?

Comment: Like you say: you mock your repository and on some method, with some parameter, you throw an Exception like SQLException. The Exception thrown by jpa will depend on some stuff :  JPA implementation / DB driver.  Also, do not test the Spring code as it is already tested!!!!! If you want to test your specific query, you can use DBUnit with a H2 database for instance.